# laravel: how do I include partials from a blade layout?

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, laravel-blade

I'd like to split my layouts into partials.

I'm creating a default blade layout.

The file is called **default.blade.php**, and lives in the `layout` folder.

Also under the layout folder is `include`.
In this dir, I have **head.blade.php**

I would like to call 'head' from 'default'.

Every one of these fails and returns an error when debug is turned on:

```
@include('include/head'),  @include('include/head.blade.php'), @include('include/head.blade.php')
```

I have copied **head.blade.php** into the same folder as **default.blade.php**, and still get errors.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You need to give the full path relative to your view folder. Try doing this :

```
@include('layout.include.head')
```

Answer (score 5):

Keep in mind that Laravel uses dot notation to organize the templates and their parts.

So, the `main.blade.php` template in your main `/views` folder should be included directly:

`@include ('main')`

A `main.blade.php` template in a, e.g. `/views/layouts` folder should be called as:

`@include ('layouts.main')`

and so on.